# Bankruptcy petitions granted by state legislatures?

Tags: legal-history, bankruptcy

In [this document](http://press-pubs.uchicago.edu/founders/documents/a4_1s2.html) we learn that someone was "discharged as an insolvent debtor, by virtue of an act of assembly of" New Jersey.

And I have learned that Thomas Chandler was similarly discharged in Vermont (then still an independent country) by an act of Vermont's legislature in June 1785.

Was it generally state legislatures that decided such cases in the 18th century?

Comment: The constitutional provision for federal control of bankruptcy law, of course, did not go into effect before 1789.

Comment: @phoog : Nonetheless I'd have guessed it would be done in courts of law rather than in legislatures.  In Vermont before the revision of the state constitution in 1786 it was not unusual for the legislature to intervene in court cases, and I know there was at least one case in Vermont before that where the legislature granted a divorce, but somehow I got an impression that in bankruptcy cases in Vermont the legislature was the court of original jurisdiction.  Now I read of the legislature doing this in New Jersey. So I'm wondering if this was normally considered a....

Comment: ....function of legislatures at that time.

Comment: That seems likely.  I know that naturalization (sic) in the UK required an act if parliament.

Comment: I also read of a divorce being granted by an act of Parliament in the 18th century.  The variation in naturalization laws in different jurisdictions is amusingly chaotic. You can become a citizen of Switzerland only by becoming a citizen of one of its cantons, and they all have their separate naturalization laws, and in some of them they leave the rules and decisions to local officials, and your application can get turned down because the mayor of the village thinks you look like a hippie.

Comment: @phoog : Where you wrote "sic", did you simply mean that that's how the still spelled that word in England at the time when acts of parliament were required for that purpose?

Comment: All I know is that that is how it was spelled in the act that naturalized G. F. Handel.

Comment: @phoog : ok..... I think the British spelled it that way around the year 1900, so it would be a 20th-century reform that changed it to "naturalisation".

Comment: Judicially granted divorces were a 19th century invention, before which divorces were granted by legislatures. Judicial bankruptcies were invented at roughly the time that debtor's prisons were abolished, mostly 19th century. Private legislation handled divorces and bankruptcy (both of which were very rarely allowed) before that.